# What technology should I use for custom iOS controls, layout etc.?

Tags: objective-c, ios, html

I'm new to iOS programming and one thing I don't get. I have an app idea, I paid for graphic designer to make me a UI design. He sent me a layered psd with custom designed controls, layout etc. Everything is custom designed, not using standard iOS looking controls as I wanted.
The question is how can be this custom design converted to iOS controls, layout and so?

If I consider a Facebook iPad application or Foursquare iPhone application, are that just "skinned" iOS standard controls, or is it written in HTML5 and just wrapped by Objective-C? If so, how?

Thank you

Comment: Use Objective-C if developing a native application, Facebook tried the HTML5 way and barely got a 2 star review in the app store.

Comment: So should I be able to skin standard iOS controls as I wish? Make my own layout? Because I didn't find any tutorial on this, in my smart books are nothing about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use Objective-C for native applications. Most controls provide support for "skinning" by allowing you to provide your own images. For example, [`UISlider`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has methods to set minimum and maximum image, the track image and tint color as well as the thumb image and tint color. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) often provides great tutorials on his site that are worth checking out.